# How to access Microsoft SQL Server database ‎for Android application?

Tags: android, android-webservice

I am  going to develop an Android application for a client. In which the data for the application is saved in the Microsoft SQL Server Database.

Usually I retrieve from MySQL database with PHP as webserver and  parsed with json, I am not having hard at it. I don't have any clue to connect with  Microsoft SQL Server Database.

I googled several times, but there is no good suggestion. Have any of you worked on it? Or if you have any ideas please share with me.

Comment: This is a popular question on stackoverflow, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492417/connect-to-sql-server-from-android

Answer (score 3):

To access it directly, you can use a JDBC driver.

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Download the jar file here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/

Sample code:

```
public void ConnectToDatabase(){
    try {
         Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         String username = "XXX";
         String password = "XXX";
         Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.188.1.1:1433/DATABASE;user=" + username + ";password=" + password);

        Log.w("Connection","open");
        Statement stmt = DbConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet reset = stmt.executeQuery(" select * from users ");


        EditText num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.displaymessage);
        num.setText(reset.getString(1));

        DbConn.close();

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
           Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```